# Using Custom UI with ADB2C sign in policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented cusom UI with sign in policy. But the UI will have content inserted by ADB2C at `<div id="api"></div>`.

Is there a way to use completely custom UI that does not render the content from ADB2C ?

My expected page is this
[image: Expected login page]

And I am getting a page like this
[image: Actual login page I am getting]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no functionality allowing that.

Custom UI is mostly just about providing your own styling (branding). All the "active" parts like forms, buttons etc. are always injected in the container you mentioned ().

There are some more possibilities of enhancing customization when using self-modified custom policies and some backend service (like Azure Functions / Proxies) but this is not trivial, in preview, and still doesn't allow full override of HTML sent do browser.

From what I can see in the image you attached most of it should be possible to handle with custom CSS by either proper visual styling of elements or hiding certain elements completely. Hiding is a kind of walk-around but at least can be made without tinkering with custom policies.
If you want to change texts (like the Sign In button) then you have to enable language customization and create a translation override (even for English). That could do the trick.
You can find more info on language customization, with examples, here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization

Comment: Thank you . I was able to achieve most of the customization with your help. Is there a way to override the page to redirect on click of Signup link as part of login page? My plan is to use custom policy for login and graph API methods for sign up. For that I need to redirect to my own page rather than Microsoft provided sign up page. Any way to achieve the same?

Comment: You can do a walk-around by providing a static sign up link in custom UI HTML and hiding the build-in one with proper CSS. Or you could use a Sign-in only policy, which doesn't render a link for creating account. But putting static content in custom UI HTML forces you to handle multiple languages for that static content by yourself. 
Can you also elaborate why do you need a custom policy for signing in and why you don't want to use sign up policy for sign up? Do you really need that?